# Run a wordpress plugin from another plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a plugin that acts as a popup for other plugins using shortcodes and it works fine apart from I got one plugin that does not use shortcodes and I have tried adding a shortcode to it but it wont work it looks like they have been disabled.

is there any way to call this plugin without the shortcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out instead of

```
$popupcode .= do_shortcode($chrp1_mykey_values[0]);
```

I am using

```
$getfunc = 'form';
$popupcode .=  $getfunc();
```

calling the function from another plugin to run it